# Startup time virtual machine EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

Can you provide me with references about the startup time of a virtual machine in EC2 of type m3.xlarge.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This will vary depending upon the Amazon Machine Image (AMI) used to boot the Amazon EC2 instance.

For example, Windows instances supplied by AWS take longer to boot because they go through a [SysPrep](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sysprep) process that involves a reboot the first time that the instance is used.

You should **measure it yourself** based upon your particular use-case.